# Error with Admin login page in PHP and mySql

Tags: php, mysql

When i run this code everything seems to be fine... But when I login with the right username and password i get the following: `That information is incorrect, try again Click Here` I should be taken to the index.php file.

I also have echo the sql query and it gave me this `Resource id #4`

Can anyone spot the problem here.

Here is the PHP

```
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);

include"db_connection.php"; 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' and password='$password' LIMIT 1");


$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount ==1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id=$row["id"];
    }

    $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
    $_SESSION["manager"]=$manager;
    $_SESSION["password"]=$password;
    header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo'That information is incorrect, try again<a href="index.php"> Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Admin Login Page</title>

<head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">

<div id="pageContent"><br/>
    <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
        <h2> Please log in To manage the store</h2>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"   action="admin_login.php">
            User Name: <br/>
            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40"/>
            <br/></br>
            Password: <br/>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            <label>
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="LogIn">
            </label>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like I always say, `echo mysql_error();` after `mysql_query()` to know why your query has failed.

Comment: Where is session_start(); ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your first two lines. You're using `$_SESSION` whereas the form submitted data will be in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra curly brace, `}`.

As good practice, **never** build a query from unescaped strings (especially if they are stored in `$_SESSION` since they can be easily hijacked), **never** store a user's password in raw format in the database, and **never** save a raw password to the session. All these issues make your application **very** vulnerable and with great security risks which not only are subject for revealing users' sensitive data, but also can compromise your system. This being said, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape user input when querying the database, you should encrypt your password with MD5/SHA/whatever (maybe add a salt too) and you should store only the user ID in the session because the other don't matter anyway.

Also, there is no reason to loop over the query results, since you are sure to have only one record returned.

Furthermore, I assume that the code you have posted is incomplete. Otherwise, your session variables won't work because you have not started a session with `session_start()`. Also, if you want to work with the username and password provided in the form, you must use `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]`, since this is how you grab the posted data, not by using sessions.

Comment: You close the `if` statement, open the `else`, then close it twice.

Comment: Have a second look. It is `if (...) {...} else {...}` not `if (...) {...} else {...} }`.